# SQL Constraint on join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have four tables in a PostgreSQL database:

- `Company`
- `User` (with a foreign key column company_id)
- `Location` (with a foreign key column company_id)
- `UserLocations` (an association table, with foreign key columns user_id and location_id)

Essentially:

- a company has many users and locations
- a user belongs to a company and has many locations
- a location belongs to a company and has many users

I want to know if there is a way for the database to constrain entries in the UserLocations association table such that the referenced user and location must have an identical company_id value. I don't want a user from company A to have a location from company B.

I can check this at my application layer (rails) but would be interested in making this a hard database level constraint if the option exists.

Comment: In the real world, a location can have several companies, and a user can have several companies.

Answer (score 5):

One way you can accomplish this is with foreign key references and redundancy.

So, the `UserLocations` table would have a `UserId`, `LocationId`, and `CompanyId`.  It would then have the following foreign key relationships:

```
foreign key (UserId, CompanyId) references Users(UserId, CompanyId)
foreign key (LocationId, CompanyId) references Locations(LocationId, CompanyId)
```

Of course, you have to declare `Users(UserId, CompanyId)` and `Locations(LocationId, CompanyId)` as unique keys for the reference.  This is a bit redundant, but it does guarantee the matching to company without creating triggers.

Answer (score 4):

Overlapping foreign key constraints are your friend.

```
create table company (
  company_id integer primary key
);

-- Reserved words include "user". Better to use identifiers that
-- are not reserved words.
create table "user" (
  user_id integer primary key,
  company_id integer not null references company (company_id),
  -- Unique constraint lets this be the target of a foreign key reference.
  unique (user_id, company_id)
);

create table location (
  location_id integer primary key,
  company_id integer not null references company (company_id),
  unique (location_id, company_id)
);

create table user_location (
  user_id integer not null,
  location_id integer not null,
  company_id integer not null,
  -- Not sure what your primary key is here. 

  -- These foreign keys overlap on the column "company_id", so there
  -- can be only one value for it.
  foreign key (user_id, company_id) references "user" (user_id, company_id),
  foreign key (location_id, company_id) references location (location_id, company_id)
);
```